# Uninstall Redis CentOs 7

Tags: centos7, redis

I installed Redis a long time ago on my CentOS 7 DirectAdmin VPS.
Now I want to remove the current version (3.0.5) and install the latest Redis 3.2.5.

How can I remove the current version?

I installed a time ago using the following commands:

```
wget http://download.redis.io/releases/redis-3.0.5.tar.gz

tar xzf redis-3.0.5.tar.gz

cd redis-3.0.5

make

make test

make install

cd utils

chmod +x install_server.sh

./install_server.sh
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, i suggest you to use your distros package instead of compiling software, this way you can upgrade and get security updates for free.

Back to your question, assuming you left the defaults during `./install_server.sh`, first stop redis:

```
/etc/init.d/redis_6379 stop
```

Delete redis's install:

`rm -fr etc/redis/ /var/log/redis_* /etc/init.d/redis_6379 /usr/local/bin/redis*`

Delete redis's data too:

```
rm -fr /var/lib/redis/6379
```

Done.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I am trying to stop redis using the first command. But than I get the following error `Stopping ...
(error) NOAUTH Authentication required. Waiting for Redis to shutdown ...
Waiting for Redis to shutdown ...
Waiting for Redis to shutdown ...` It keeps waiting. What am I missing?

Comment: For the time being you can `killall -9 redis-server` - this PR should resolve the issue in the fullness of time: https://github.com/antirez/redis/pull/2069

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me for centos 7

```
sudo yum remove redis
```

you can have a look [here](https://docs.redislabs.com/latest/rs/installing-upgrading/uninstalling/) instead of using redis labs ,I used `redis`